# How can I set a default Instance URL for my Android App

Tags: android, mobile, sugarcrm

I've been working on an app to test Sugar Mobile SDK. I would like to get the Instance URL prefilled to make it easier for users.

[image: App with empty field]

So I have tried on app.json with these two options:

```
"jsConfig": {
    "siteUrl": "https://ps*****/",
    "defaultServerUrl": "https://ps*****/",
```

I also built a release version with --site-url https://ps****** and I uploaded it to my Internal testing in Google Play.

I update my app from Play store but I keep getting an empty field.

I found this in documentation:

```
siteUrl - string - Specifies Sugar server instance URL. Used by web app only. **Native app uses the loginUrl to build the server URL.**
```

So now I cannot find where that loginUrl is, or it's just that empty field value?.

I would like to confirm wether it's possible to set a default value for an android app or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Eugene Bychkov, who answered this in Sugar Community!

The settings are:

```
"jsConfig": {
    "loginSettings": {
         "editable": true,
         "defaultServerUrl": "https://psn-test.sugaropencloud.eu"

    },
```

These loginSettings documentation is in https://mobiletools.sugarcrm.com/docs/latest/sdk/docs/sdk/Config.jsConfig.loginSettings.html